# Linear Programming: understanding a special maximum-ratio rule for deciding a leaving variable

Tags: linear-programming

In my book, the following rule for choosing a leaving variable is given:

$$x_k=\big(\max_{i\in B}\frac{\bar{a}_{ik}}{\bar{b}_i}\big)^{-1}$$

$$$$

But let us say you get the following scenario:

$$ratios_1  = \big(\frac{-3}{4}, \frac{-7}{3}, \frac{0}{0}\big)$$

What is the maximum of list of ratios? Is it $\frac{0}{0}$ ? How do I return the inverse of this?

The lets have another senario:

$$ratios_2  = \big(\frac{-3}{4}, \frac{1}{3}, \frac{3}{0}\big)$$

My book says that if the denominator vanishes,

> "If the numerator is nonzero, then it is easy to see that the ratio should be interpreted as plus or minus
> infinity depending on the sign of the numerator".

So then the list should be:

$$ratios_2  = \big(\frac{-3}{4}, \frac{1}{3}, +\infty\big)$$

So the maximum of this list is $+\infty$. So, should I then take the inverse of infinity, how do I do so?

Comment: The fraction with 0 at the denominator cannot be part of the list you  choose of.

Comment: Really? My book has an example where they get the two fraction: 0/2 and 3/0. They then say that 3/0 is equal infinity. They then go on and say that infinity is the max and pick corresponding leaving variable

Comment: See my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2404519/144421) It is the rule to choose the pivot row.

Comment: Maybe the rule is in context of sensitivity analysis. These rules are much more difficult. I always look them up, when I use them.

Comment: Thank you for your help! :)